# close window in angularjs on specific url angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webview

I am new to angularjs , so this question might seems silly to experience ones , But i really not able to perform this , can any body tell me that how to come back to app from webview after reaching to specific url , Like i am opening a window in browser for payment process so what i need is that when url in webview comes up with a success msg , i want to close the webview and get back to my application , I goggled and found a way that in $window.open() we pass three parameters and through second i can do that , but don't know how to implement that , can any one provide me a way to deal that.

i studied thi link :- [Tracking a child window across page loads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776524/tracking-a-child-window-across-page-loads)

i tried this function too :-

```js
 if (!$window.closed){ 
 if($window.location.href =="http://www.magentomobileshop.com/demo/index.php/payu/index/success")
 {
    $window.close()
   }
                 
 }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look on it :-
[Close a child window in an Android app made with Angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28752424/close-a-child-window-in-an-android-app-made-with-angularjs)

here is my updated Answer ...and I have tested it 
and its working fine

```js
var url = "test_Url";

var socialLoginWindow = window
  .open(url,
    '_blank',
    'location=no');
// listen to page load
// events
socialLoginWindow
  .addEventListener(
    'loadstart',
    function(
      event) {
      var url = event.url;
      if (url == "http://www.magentomobileshop.com/demo/index.php/payu/index/success/") {
        socialLoginWindow
          .close();
      }

    });
```

And here is the reference link for it :-

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/opening-external-link-and-closing-it-at-an-event/6660/9

Here "Loadstart" will track your every change of url in window.So, the current URL can be get from event.url

Cheers !!!
Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

Use $window.close() in $window service.
You can broadcast the result to another controller like this AngularJS – Communicating Between Controllers

can you check if this will answer your question
    [How to close browser window in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19041484/how-to-close-browser-window-in-angularjs)

You can use the $window.location.href to check for the particular URL to be true

Comment: Hey Makb , how can i check the url in webview, so that i can close my webview on that perticular Url.